# Android HTML View

Tags: android, webview

Using Android, I have a WebView. I create html locally which includes references to css, javascript and images in the Assets folder. This local html is then displayed.

How do I get the WebView to reference the Assets' javascript and images?

I am guessing I need to tell the HTML VIew that the base folder is the Assets folder? If so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649111/android-webview-loading-javascript-file-in-assets-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should acces the file `index.html` using this location:

```
file:///android_asset/index.html
```

Comment: The content is created dynamically in memory, it's only the java script and images that I need to link to .

Comment: Ok I think you can access the CSS and JS files the same way.