# Android Web-View : Inject local Javascript file to Remote Webpage

Tags: javascript, android, caching, webview

It has been asked many times before, I browsed through everything, no clear answers yet.

Question simplified: Is it possible to inject local Javascript file (from asset or storage) to remote webpage loaded in an Android Web-View? I know that it is possible to inject such files to local Webpages (Assets HTML) loaded in a Web-View.

Why do I need this to work? : To make browsing experience faster, by avoiding downloading of bigger files such as Js and CSS files every time. I want to avoid Web-View Caching.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There is a way to 'force' the injection of your local Javascript files from local assets (e.g., assets/js/script.js), and to circumvent the 'Not allowed to load local resource : file:///android_assets/js/script.js ...' issue.

It is similar to what described in another thread ([Android webview, loading javascript file in assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649111/android-webview-loading-javascript-file-in-assets-folder)), with additional BASE64 encoding/decoding for representing your Javascript file as a printable string.

I am using an Android 4.4.2, API level 19 Virtual Device.

Here are some code snippets:

[assets/js/script.js]:

```
    'use strict';

    function test() {
       // ... do something
    }

    // more Javascript
```

[MainActivity.java]:

```
    ...

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
       @Override
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          return false;
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
          super.onPageFinished(view, url);

          injectScriptFile(view, "js/script.js"); // see below ...

          // test if the script was loaded
          view.loadUrl("javascript:setTimeout(test(), 500)");
       }

       private void injectScriptFile(WebView view, String scriptFile) {
          InputStream input;
          try {
             input = getAssets().open(scriptFile);
             byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
             input.read(buffer);
             input.close();

             // String-ify the script byte-array using BASE64 encoding !!!
             String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.NO_WRAP);
             view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                          "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                          "var script = document.createElement('script');" +
                          "script.type = 'text/javascript';" +
             // Tell the browser to BASE64-decode the string into your script !!!
                          "script.innerHTML = window.atob('" + encoded + "');" +
                          "parent.appendChild(script)" +
                          "})()");
          } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
    });

    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. However it works only for android version upto 4.3. For Android 4.4, it says I have to run the loading thing (loadUrl) inside the UI thread only and when I do that using RunOnUIThread() it does nothing, I mean it loads nothing. Do you know what can be the problem?

Comment: @sumit In Android 4.4 I use `Runnable` objects as follows: first, I define a `Handler` in class `MainActivity ... { final Handler handler = new Handler(); ...`. Second, in my method I use a `Runnable` object, e.g. `void loadWebPage() { final Runnable r = new Runnable() { public void run() { WebView myWebView = ... } }; handler.post(r) }`. I hope it helps.

Comment: I was doing the same but it didnt work. The reason  is, in Kitkat version it is not possible to inject js file locally using view.loadUrl(). I had to use evaluateJavaScript() method and it worked. To inject file CSS files one can use view.loadUrl(), but for js, evaluateJavaScript() has to be used. Welcome to ChromeView :)

Comment: This is an awesome answer! I only have one problem with it, it doesn't work with the asset you want to inject is in UTF-8 and outside of the ANSI character range. I was able to fix it by changing the decode to this: "script.innerHTML = decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob('" + encoded + "')));" +

Comment: Genius genius!!! you saved my day bro! I have posted a question with 200 bounty. If you post answer under that I can accept your answer. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51570906/how-to-add-javascript-function-in-webview-and-call-it-later-from-html

Comment: Worked for me in a modified way. I changed `setTimeout(test(), 500)` to `setTimeout(test, 0)`. First, you don't want to call the `test` function _immediately_, you want `setTimeout` to call it (though it works both ways!). Second, why wait 500ms; You can just queue the function call to run immediately when ready.

Comment: This worked for me with some minor changes and with `setTimeout` too. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

loadUrl will work only in old version use [evaluateJavascript](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript%28java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29)

```
webview.evaluateJavascript("(function() { document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value='USERNAME';document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value='PASSWORD'; "+
"return { var1: \"variable1\", var2: \"variable2\" }; })();", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                    Log.d("LogName", s); // Prints: {"var1":"variable1","var2":"variable2"}
                }
            });
```

Comment: What is clientLogin? aha... the webview

Comment: This requires minSdkVersion 19 or higher.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you could use shouldInterceptRequest() to intercept remote url loading and return local stored content.

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, String url) {
       if (url.equals("script_url_to_load_local")) {
           return new WebResourceResponse("text/javascript", "UTF-8", new FileInputStream("local_url")));
       } else {
           return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a better solution, as you can run Javascript more consistently.

Comment: Note that `shouldInterceptRequest(WebView, String)` has been superseded by `shouldInterceptRequest(WebView, WebResourceRequest)`. This solution still works (except that you have to check `request.getUrl()` and remember that its type is `Uri`). Also note that if you use `WebView.loadData()` without a base URL, you cannot use relative paths in `<script src="...">`, seems that `WebView` ignores them. Use `loadDataWithBaseURL()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful using `evaluateJavascript`: if there is a syntax error or exception thrown in your javascript it will call your `onReceiveValue` with a null.  The most common way to support both SDK 19 as well as lower seems to be like this:[Fill form in WebView with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187908/fill-form-in-webview-with-javascript/32115462#32115462)

Also if you get terribly desperate for some kind of browser functionality (in my case, never could figure out how to get DRM to work well) you could use a bookmarklet within normal chrome, which works only if you type the bookmark name into the omnibox but does work and does inject javascript.

Also be aware that with the default `WebView` you can't use javascript alerts to test anything, they don't show. Also be aware that "video" by default (like html <video> tags) doesn't "really work" by default and also DRM video doesn't work by default, they're all configure options :\