# how to disable the header and footer in android webview for a particular url?

Tags: android, webview

I'm loading a particular url in a  webview. From that URL, I'm going to another webpage/URL. How to disable the header and footer of the second URL?

Comment: AFAIK You cannot do it directly from `WebView` in android. I would suggest to have a javascript function in your webpage and inject javascript function call from `webview` to disable header and footer when function is invoked

Comment: Can you please help me with that? code for the js function and also how to inject it in webview

Comment: You can have a look at this answer to see webview javascript call
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552912/android-web-view-inject-local-javascript-file-to-remote-webpage