# How to add a JavaScript function in WebView and call it later from HTML upon submitting reCAPTCHA

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview, recaptcha

I am adding a JavaScript function in WebView like this (Kotlin):

```
val webView = findViewById(R.id.webview) as WebView
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "android")
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false)
webView.loadUrl(url)

webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function captchaResponse (token){" +
                        "      android.reCaptchaCallbackInAndroid(token);" +
                        "    })()")
    }
}
```

The function works fine, but the problem is that it runs immediately, when I add it in WebView. I only want to include it as a JavaScript function and it should be called only from the HTML, when the user will fill the reCAPTCHA. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you need to load the javascript function dynamically? Else you can load it as part of the html itself using script tag inside head in html.

Comment: I have to load it dynamically @SaikrishnaRajaraman

Comment: Try reference the javascript files inside the html.

Comment: Is your HTML is a local file or coming from server?

Comment: see here https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview

Comment: @PravinDivraniya HTML file is coming from server and I can not change it in any case. In android I can do anything to make it work

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552912/android-web-view-inject-local-javascript-file-to-remote-webpage) and [this](https://medium.com/@filipe.batista/inject-javascript-into-webview-2b702a2a029f)

Comment: @ZohabAli Do you want to add the recaptcha button when webview loads and upon click of recaptcha button you want to perform any action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try injecting the script like this,

```
function addCode(code){
var addedScript= document.createElement('script');
addedScript.text= code;
document.body.appendChild(addedScript);}
```

now call the function like,

```
val codeToExec = "function captchaResponse (token){" +
                    "android.reCaptchaCallbackInAndroid(token);" +
                    "}";
```

now exec loadurl like,

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function addCode(code){
var addedScript= document.createElement('script');
addedScript.text= code;
document.body.appendChild(addedScript);})(codeToExec));
```

Answer (score 10):

In order to run your `reCaptchaCallbackInAndroid` exposed method from JavaScript, when the user submitted a **successful** reCAPTCHA response, first make sure, to **actually listen** to the reCAPTCHA `callback` via [**`g-recaptcha` tag attributes**](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param):

```
<div class="g-recaptcha"
     data-sitekey="{{your site key}}"
     data-callback="myCustomJavaScriptCallback"
></div>
```

or via the [**reCAPTCHA v2 JavaScript API**](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api):

```
grecaptcha.render(
  'g-recaptcha-element-id', {
    sitekey: '{{your site key}}',
    callback: 'myCustomJavaScriptCallback'
  }
)
```

then, when the page finished loading in the `WebView`, add your JavaScript callback function to the [**`window` object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) using `webView.loadUrl`:

```
webView.loadUrl("""
    javascript:(function() {
        window.myCustomJavaScriptCallback = function(token) {                
            android.reCaptchaCallbackInAndroid(token);
        }
    })()
""".trimIndent())
```

and finally, when the user submits a **successful reCAPTCHA response**, your `myCustomJavaScriptCallback` will be called and through that, your exposed `reCaptchaCallbackInAndroid` method too with the reCAPTCHA `token`.

- Since you're using Kotlin, in this case, you can just simply use [**multiline string literals**](https://realkotlin.com/tutorials/2018-06-26-multiline-string-literals-in-kotlin/).
- **Since you're exposing a method to JavaScript, make sure to know the [security concerns](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips#WebView).**
- In case you'll need additional JavaScript injection in the future (more method exposure, DOM manipulation, etc.), [**check out this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552912/android-web-view-inject-local-javascript-file-to-remote-webpage?noredirect=1&lq=1).

---

## In your case:

Set reCAPTCHA to call your `captchaResponse` JavaScript function via `tag attribute`:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha"
     ...
     data-callback="captchaResponse"
     ...
></div>
```

or via its `API`:

```
grecaptcha.render(
  '...', {
    ...
    callback: 'captchaResponse'
    ...
  }
)
```

and add your `captchaResponse` callback function to `window`:

```
webView.loadUrl("""
    javascript:(function() {
        window.captchaResponse = function(token) {
            // your code here before the Android callback...

            android.reCaptchaCallbackInAndroid(token);
            
            // ...or after the Android callback
        }
    })()
""".trimIndent())
```

---

## Test:

Here's a simple, `Empty Activity` in Android Studio (using Kotlin) with a basic `LinearLayout` *(an `EditText` and a `Button` within the layout)* and the `MainActivity.kt`:

```js
package com.richrdkng.injectjsintowebview

import android.net.Uri
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        sendButton.setOnClickListener { loadWebpage() }
    }

    @Throws(UnsupportedOperationException::class)
    fun buildUri(authority: String) : Uri {
        val builder = Uri.Builder()
        builder.scheme("https")
                .authority(authority)
        return builder.build()
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    fun reCaptchaCallbackInAndroid(token: String) {
        val tok = token.substring(0, token.length / 2) + "..."
        Toast.makeText(this.applicationContext, tok, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    fun loadWebpage() {
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "android")
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false)
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.richrdkng.com/recaptcha-v2-test/")

        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                webView.loadUrl("""
                    javascript:(function() {
                        window.onCaptchaSuccess = function(token) {
                            android.reCaptchaCallbackInAndroid(token);
                        }
                    })()
                """.trimIndent())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then using a [simple reCAPTCHA v2 test website](https://www.richrdkng.com/recaptcha-v2-test), the `window.onCaptchaSuccess` function is called upon a successful reCAPTCHA submission and the reCAPTCHA token is partially displayed in a [`Toast`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast) using an Android Emulator:

[image: virtual machine with successful reCAPTCHA v2]

---

***Full disclosure: I made the [reCAPTCHA v2 test website](https://www.richrdkng.com/recaptcha-v2-test) to prepare/test/debug similar situations.***

Comment: I cannot just use webView.loadUrl to push javascript code. Problem is the javascript code that I am pushing contains script which hides the recaptcha. So when I add it with webView.loadUrl it runs immediately and hides recaptcha. I am already doing exactly same thing which you have described. All I want is that javascript code should not be executed IMMEDIATELY when I add it to webview

Comment: @ZohabAli, can you please update your question and post the **full code** you want to run including **hiding the reCAPTCHA with all the additional details you want/need to do**, so I can update my answer accordingly? Also, please post the HTML code too, so we can help you better. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your solution helped me and my team to solve a not so simple problem. Can you please check the recaptcha link in your answer? Thx!

Comment: Fixed and updated. You're welcome!