# How to load a Javascript in WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview, inject

I have loaded my Webpage in Android WebView using `webview.loadUrl()` and I am trying to inject a Javascript into the WebView using `webview.evaluateJavascript()`.

But the problem here is, the Javascript is available in a remote location/url. I want to get the javascript from a remote location and inject it into WebView.

I have searched related to this question but all I have found is loading from string.

Comment: You will need to download it yourself with an http library like okhttp

Comment: 1) get Javascript from `remote location/url.` 2) inject it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
private static class WC extends WebViewClient {
    Handler handler1 = null;
    WebView webView = null;
    byte[] b = null;

    public WC(Handler handler, WebView webView) {
        this.handler1 = handler;
        this.webView = webView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    injectScriptFromNetWork("http://192.168.216.254:4000/test.js");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }

    private void injectScriptFromNetWork(String urlStr) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (code == 200) {
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            b = new byte[inputStream.available()];
            inputStream.read(b);
        }

        handler1.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String jsSource = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                        "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                        "var script = document.createElement('script');" +
                        "script.type = 'text/javascript';" +
                        "script.innerHTML = window.atob('" + jsSource + "');" +
                        "parent.appendChild(script)" +
                        "})()");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java code like this:

```
handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
webView.setWebViewClient(new WC(handler, webView));
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Forgave me, this is my first time answering questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: SO users always try to improve things, no apologies required. You can visit StackOverflow code of conduct to know how to write good question/answer. Your answer is primarily code-based. try to explain it rather giving a code snippet only. It will help the community for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

To enable javascript try this.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

myWebView .loadUrl("url");
```

To get the javascript from a remote location see [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21612566/4854891)